# array and matrix multiplication in mips

Tags: assembly, mips, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply A*X and sum with B. thus, (A*X)+B. However, it's not working and additionally I need to find max num in result of A
A is 5*3 matrix and B is array which is 3 and C is also array of 5 numbers

I'm asking how to fix that error and what is wrong in my code
Additionally I can't make code that find max number in the result of matrix A

the errors are like this:
 Exception occurred at PC=0x00400084
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10040100
 Exception occurred at PC=0x00400084
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10040114

```
la $s4, matrixA     #s4 set to base address of matrixA
la $s3, vectorX     #s3 set to base address of vectorX
la $s7, vectorB     #s7 set to base address of vectorB
la $s5, shapeA       #s5 set to base address of sizeA
nop
lw $s6, 4($s5)      #s6 set to second val in sizeA (col#)
nop
lw $s5, 0($s5)      #s5 set to first val in sizeA (row#)

lw $t1, 0($s5) # $t1 = 32 (row size/loop end)
li $s0, 0  # i = 0; initialize 1st for loop
L1:  li $s1,0  #j=0;restart2ndforloop
L2:  li $s2,0  #k=0;restart3rdforloop

mul $t2, $s0, $s5 #$t2 = A[row](size of row of B)
addiu $t2, $t2, 0 # $t2 = i * size(row) + 0
sll  $t2, $t2, 2   # $t2 = byte offset of [i][0]
addu $t2, $s7, $t2 # $t2 = byte address of B[i][0]
l.d $f4, 0($t2) # $f4 = 4 bytes of B[i][0]

L3: mul $t0,$s2,$s5   #$t0 = i * A[col](size of row of X)
addiu $t0, $t0, 0 # $t0 = k * size(row) + 0
sll  $t0, $t0, 2   # $t0 = byte offset of X[k][0]
addu $t0, $s3, $t0 # $t0 = byte address of X[k][0]
l.d $f16, 0($t0)   # $f16 = 4 bytes of X[k][0]

mul $t0,$s0,$s5 #$t0 = i * A[row](size of row of A)
addu $t0, $t0, $s2 # $t0 = i * size(row) + k
sll $t0, $t0, 2 # $t0 = byte offset of A[i][k]
addu $t0, $s4, $t0   # $t0 = byte address of A[i][k]
l.d $f18, 0($t0)   # $f18 = 4 bytes of A[i][k]

mul.d $f16, $f18, $f16 # $f16 = y[i][k] * z[k][j]
add.d $f4, $f4, $f16 # $f4=x[i][j] + y[i][k]*z[k][j]

addiu $s2, $s2, 1 # k = k + 1
bne $s2,$t1,L3
s.d $f4, 0($t2)

addiu $s2, $s2, 1 # j = j + 1
bne $s2,$t1,L2
addiu $s0, $s0, 1 # i = i + 1
bne $s0,$t1,L1 #if(i!=32)gotoL1
```

Comment: `lw $t1, 0($s5)` is incorrect as $s5 is not an address. Probably, according to your comment you mean `move $t1,$s5`

Comment: I changed but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I definitely do not understand your code. You state that you want to do matrix-vector multiplication, but in your comments you have "x[i][j] + y[i][k]*z[k][j]". When I see address computation, I feel that you are processing floats, but in the code, it seems more related to doubles....

Matrix vector multiplication do not require complex address computation and can be done by just incrementing pointers.

It is much better to separate loop counting and address computation in you code and to reverse the tests in the loops.

C code b[] += a[][]*x[]

```
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    double r=b[i];
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      r+=a[i][j]*x[j];
    }
    b[i]=r;
  }
```

This can be rewritten with pointers

```
  pb=&b[0] ;
  pa=&a[0][0];
  for (i=0;i<N;i++){
    px=&x[0];
    r=*pb;
    for (j=O;j<M;j++){
      r = r + *px * *pa;
      px++;
      pa++;
    }
    *pb=r ;
    pb++ ;
  }
```

And the mips version, that is a direct translation of the latter C code

```
        la $s1, matrixA     #s1 set to base address of matrixA pa
        la $s2, vectorB     #s2 set to base address of vectorB pb
        la $s3, vectorX     #s3 set to base address of vectorX px
        # s4 temps for the @vectorX
        la $s5, shapeA      #s5 set to base address of sizeA
        lw $s6, 4($s5)      #s6 set to second val in sizeA (col#)
        lw $s5, 0($s5)      #s5 set to first val in sizeA (row#)

L1:     move $t1,$0         # i=0
        move $s4,$s3        # $s4 == px
        l.d $f0,0($s2)      # f0=r=*pb

L2:     move $t2,$0         # j=0
        l.d $f2,0($s1)      # $f2 *pa=a[i]][j]
        l.d $f4,0($s4)      # $f4 *px=x[j]
        mul.d $f2,$f2,$f4   # a[i][j]*x[j]
        add.d $f0,$f0,$f2   # +b[i]
        addi $t2,$t2,1      # j++
        addi $s1,$s1,8      # pa++
        addi $s4,$s4,8      # px++
        bne  $t2,$s6,L2     # j!=N?->L2

        s.d  $f0,0($s2)     # *pb=r
        addi $s2,$s2,8      # pb++
        addi $t1,$t1,1      # i++
        bne  $t1,$6,L1      # j!=M?->L1
```

EDIT: fixed errors (thanks @Peter)

Comment: but it makes error                                                                                             parser) syntax error on line 20 of file /Users/1nhee/Desktop/stackoverflow.asm
   li $t1,$s5          # i=M

Comment: @ineedyourhelp: presumably those are supposed to be `move`, not `li`.  Just a brain fart I think; maybe Alain first wrote it with `N` and `M` as assemble-time constants instead of register inputs.

Comment: @Alain: `bne` takes 2 register inputs.  Maybe you mean `bnez` (a pseudo-op for bne against `$zero`).  Or better, calculate an end address outside the loop and use `bne $s1, $t9, L2` to loop like `do { pa++ } while(pa != endpa)` instead of needing to decrement a separate counter inside the loop.

Comment: Also, @ineedyourhelp posted a broken version of your code as a non-answer.  I don't see what they changed, and they don't say what exception or where, so probably that should just get deleted.  IDK if it would improve the question for that attempt to get edited into the question, though.  Probably best if you can just update your answer to something that assembles, although writing a full `main:` that returns after might be still something to leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Alain slt  $t5,$t2,$t2 bne  $t5,$zero,L2        # I changed it like this but it's making more errors

Comment: Fixed the code. I did first version rapidly, without testing. But now it assembles properly in mars. I kept the seperate i/j counters to keep the code close to C. But this in real code this is a good optimization.

Comment: Since you have `N` in a register anyway, you might as well count up and use `beq` if you care about looking like the C source.  At least you're not insisting on a stupid loop with `if()break` at the top and a `j top` at the bottom, though, and instead using an idiomatic do{}while style asm loop.